# What is the calculation of Ngram?

Tags: python, n-gram

I'm doing a projcet of dating books, and my main idea is to do it with "ngram".
I entered here http://books.google.com/ngrams and I found the ngrams that have the most unequivocal graphs (unconstant value over the years).
Then I wrote a code in python that "reads" books - it take the book, some ngrams, and then calculates the frequanty of the ngrams over the text. For example, the ngram "ex" in the text "extarminate all human beings with explosive grandes" would be  0.05263157894736842 because there's 2 "ex"'s in this text and there's 38 possible 2-letters combinations, so I thought the ngram would be 2/38.

So I did this calculation on a lot of books with 1gram (the ABC) and I got more or less the same numbers with all the books. And then I went back to Google's ngram, and apparently the numbers I got and the number they got were completly different. For example, the 1gram "a" was around 0.078, b was 0.0135 and so one, but Google's ngram was [a=1.54] and [b=0.0066]...

I reached the conclusion that I've got this calculation all wrong. Now, I'm asking you what is the **REAL** calculation of ngram's. I really need to understand this so please, if you know how this thing works, please let me know.

Thanks alot :)

Edit after answered: I really got higher values than Google, because my valuse are probability (0 to 1), so if I want to convert this values to %'s I have to multiply by 100, and it make sense because there is more "a" (8%) as a letter in the english language than "a" as a word.

Comment: You're computing character n-gram statistics. Google uses word n-grams.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure about the value that you're reporting from Google?  Frequencies range from 0 to 1, and you're citing 1.54 as their result.  I would check that if I were you.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_frequency

This says the letter `a` has a frequency of 0.08167.

You should also realize that this frequency is based on a particular sample.  You're assuming that the frequency of the appearance of the letter approaches the true value as the sample size becomes large enough.

I usually think of words when I hear n-gram.  A 1-gram is a single word (e.g. "apple"); a tri-gram is three words (e.g. "We the people").

Comment: -Are you sure that 1-gram is a single word?
-Thanks, I will read about the Letter frequncy, but I still think about the n-gram as a best option because I have Google's graphs of frequency vs. years and it would really help me with dating the books. The problem is that I don't understand their calculation and therfore I don't get the same numbers...

-I want to use also 2-grams, 3-grams or 4-grams (by that I mean combinations of 2,3 and 4 letters), but I also saw a different between my values and Google values with 2-grams.

Comment: I don't want to use a constant value because I want to date the books, so I want to know the difference over years of the frequency of the N-gram

Comment: Yes, I'm sure about n-grams referring to words as well as letters.

Comment: N-grams can be calculated at both character and word levels; which one is appropriate depends on the task.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I did some research and @duffymo was actually right.
It doesn't matter if it's a word or a letter, Google's Ngram Engine would search it in a form of a signle phrase. For example, if I write "a", it would search " a " (with spaces) as a single word.

I made some changes in my code and now I'm getting the same results as Google.

Thanks!